# wiki WITH modern browsing/searching/filtering

Tags: search, wiki, content-filtering

I'm trying to create a website that allows access-controlled wiki-style article creation WITH modern browsing, searching and filtering of this content. The issue is platforms like mediawiki or docuwiki do not seem to have either builtin or obvious plugins that enable what I would call "modern" searching, filtering etc (eg, search with autocomplete, real-time filtering of results by tags, etc). This kind of functionality is usually associated with ecommerce-style web platforms which lack wiki functionality.

I've included a mockup of what such site might look like. [image: mockup]

Does anyone have any suggestions for platforms which might natively or through plugins have both sets of functionality? Or at least a platform that would be a good base from which to code any additional needed functionality?

Thanks!